# ¿Como continuar la ejecucion si se produce un error en C#?

Tags: c#

Necesito que un programa c# siga funcionando luego de conseguir un error. Algo asi como "On Error resume next" de VB.

ejemplo: tengo un foreach que lee todos los directorios y si alguno es de solo lectura arroja un error y por supesto el programa se detiene. Yo deseo que continue hasta que termine de mostrar todos.

```
try
{
    IEnumerable<string> allFilesInAllFolders = Directory.EnumerateFiles("c:\\", "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

    foreach (var file in allFilesInAllFolders) //El error se produce aqui
    {
        Console.WriteLine(file);
    }
}
catch (System.UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine( ex.Message);
    
}
```

Si lo coloco en un bloque try{}catch{} captura el error y se sale.Repito Yo quiero que continue.

Por favor no me digan que no es recomendable o alguna explicacion de porque no se debe usar. Gracias de antemano

Lo edite para evitar la confusión.

Comment: ¿ Y qué pones en la clausula catch{} ?

Comment: podria poner el codigo con el try catch, porque eso deberia funcionar

Comment: El try/catch debería ir dentro del for, para que no se salga

Comment: @Yussef es la función **EnumerateFiles** la que lanza la excepción.

Comment: Creo que eso no es posible. Al menos con la función `Directory.EnumerateFiles`. Aunque siempre puedes escribir tu propia versión de una función. Podrías usar esas mismas funciones pero ir tú mismo directorio por directorio listando los archivos. Claro que deberías agregar un try catch para que el programa no crashee. Quizá esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60197131) te ayude.

Comment: @Mateo Yo creo que el error está dentro del for, él dice "Yo deseo que continue hasta que termine de mostrar todos."... Habrá a esperar a ver si responde

Comment: Edite la parte del programa y les indico donde se produce el error.  En la 1ra linea del foreach

Comment: Lo que no me quedó claro es qué error se produce

Comment: En ese ejemplo se produce un error de acceso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algo así podría funcionar:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IEnumerable<string> allFilesInAllFolders = Directory.EnumerateFiles("c:\\", "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            var Iterador = allFilesInAllFolders.GetEnumerator();
            while (hayNext(Iterador))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Iterador.Current);
            }
        }

        private static bool hayNext(IEnumerator<string> ITer)
        {
            try
            {
                return ITer.MoveNext();
            }
            catch
            {
                return hayNext(ITer);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Gracias por ese codigo. Aparentemente funciona como se debe